# Why is record missing while using limit and offset in mysql?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, limit, offset

Lets say I have a table Product. I have few thousands record in my table.

When I tried
The `offset_val = 0,10,20,30...`

```
Product.where("live" => true).offset(offset_val).limit(10).order("position DESC")
```

Executing the same query with different offset_val,

It returns me the live product only 10 at a time, but found some records are missing in the result

Any constraint or situation will have this problem?

```
  Sample Record Set =[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,.....,20]
    Expected Output 
    when offset_val = 10  & limit = 10
    => [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]
   Actual Output => [10,11,12,13,15,16,17,18,20,21]
```

Comment: Are you sure the `live` is `true` for the missing product?

Comment: check the value of "live" it must be false for few records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just make sure that `"live" => true` for the missing records